# NSURL with JSON returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm keep getting a `(null)` error when I try to build my NSURL to open another app.

The URL should be

`ms-test-app://eventSourceId=evtSrcId&eventID=13675016&eventType=0&json={"meterresults":[{"clean":"2","raw":"2","status":"0"}]}`

but when I try to build my URL it's always null.

At first I thought it has something to do with the URL itself, but it's the same as I got it from the example [here](https://github.com/Movilizer/movilizer-external-events-ios).

Another thought was that IOS got some problems with the double quotes in the JSON, but I replaced them with `%22`, but this doesn't work either.

Here is the code, where I build the URL:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%22meterresults%22:[{%22clean%22:%22%@%22,%22raw%22:%22%@%22,%22status%22:%22%@%22}]}", cleanReadingString, rawReadingString, status];

NSLog(@"JSON= %@",jsonString);

//Send the result JSON back to the movilizer app
NSString *eventSourceId = @"evtSrcId";
NSString *encodedQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?eventSourceId=%@&eventID=%d&eventType=0&json=%@",
                                eventSourceId, _eventId, jsonString];[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                    [_endpointUrls objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)_selectedEndpoint]],
                    encodedQueryString];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
```

I don't know where I'm wrong and I would be glad if someone got any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your code throws any warnings/errors ? Because `NSString *encodedQueryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?eventSourceId=%@&eventID=%d&eventType=0&json=%@", eventSourceId, _eventId, jsonString];[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]` should...

Comment: Can you really send JSON as a URL parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I found my error. The problem where the braces and I had to replace `encodedQueryString` with `[jsonString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]`. In that way all braces and double quotes are encoded, which creates a valid URL. But I still got the problem, that the other app doesn't really process the URL.

Comment: @Droppy I don't know if this is really possible. It's strange for me to but it's the same, as it's in the example. The app im calling is from another company and I have to wait for their response if this is possible or if there's another error.

Comment: I think it's extremely unlikely to work.  I think you need to use a POST request with the JSON as the content.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using `NSURLComponents` to create URLs rather than trying to format them into a string.

```
  NSDictionary* jsonDict = @{@"clean": @"2", @"raw": @"2", @"status": @"0"};
  NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonDict options:0 error:NULL];
  NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSURLComponents* components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] init];
  components.scheme = @"ms-test-app";
  components.queryItems = @[
                        [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"eventSourceId" value:eventSourceId],
                        [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"eventID" value:@(_eventId).stringValue],
                        [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"json" value:jsonString]
                        ];
  NSURL* url = components.URL;
```

Once you build the URL that way, it becomes apparent that your string doesn't have a host portion (or more accurately, one of your parameters is being used as the host portion).

The other comments about not being able to send JSON as an URL parameter are incorrect. As long as the system on the other side that is parsing the query string can handle it, you can send anything you want as an URL parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the error. The problem was the `eventSourceId` which needs to be a number and this was the cause of the problem.

Comment: I got an additional note to your solution. The URL I built was missing the two slashes, so I added `components.host = @"";` which seems to be necessary for those.